# GSON: How to move fields to parent object

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to transform my Java object to JSON.

Currently I'm having the following structure:

```
"Step": {
  "start_name": "Start",
  "end_name": "End",
  "data": {
    "duration": {
      "value": 292,
      "text": "4 min."
    },
    "distance": {
       "value": 1009.0,
       "text": "1 km"
    },
    "location": {
       "lat": 59.0000,
       "lng": 9.0000,
       "alt": 0.0
    }
  }
}
```

Currently a `Duration` object is inside a `Data` object. I would like to skip the `Data` object and move the `Duration` object to the `Step` object, like this:

```
"Step": {
  "start_name": "Start",
  "end_name": "End",
  "duration": {
    "value": 292,
    "text": "4 min."
  },
  "distance": {
     "value": 1009.0,
     "text": "1 km"
  },
  "location": {
     "lat": 59.0000,
     "lng": 9.0000,
     "alt": 0.0
  }
}
```

How can I do this using GSON?

EDIT: I've tried to use a TypeAdapter to modify the Step.class, but in the write-method I'm not able to add my duration object to the JsonWriter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can probably do this by writing, and then registering a [custom serializer](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) for `Step`, and making sure inside it you work with `Duration` etc, instead of `Data`.

```
// registering your custom serializer:
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder ();
builder.registerTypeAdapter (Step.class, new StepSerializer ());
Gson gson = builder.create ();
// now use 'gson' to do all the work
```

The code for the custom serializer below, I'm writing off the top of my head. It misses exception handling, and might not compile, and does slow things like create instances of `Gson` repeatedly. But it represents the *kind of thing* you'll want to do:

```
class StepSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Step>
{
  public JsonElement serialize (Step src,
                                Type typeOfSrc,
                                JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
      Gson gson = new Gson ();
      /* Whenever Step is serialized,
      serialize the contained Data correctly.  */
      JsonObject step = new JsonObject ();
      step.add ("start_name", gson.toJsonTree (src.start_name);
      step.add ("end_name",   gson.toJsonTree (src.end_name);

      /* Notice how I'm digging 2 levels deep into 'data.' but adding
      JSON elements 1 level deep into 'step' itself.  */
      step.add ("duration",   gson.toJsonTree (src.data.duration);
      step.add ("distance",   gson.toJsonTree (src.data.distance);
      step.add ("location",   gson.toJsonTree (src.data.location);

      return step;
    }
}
```

Comment: I only need to `serialize`, so `deserialize` is not important. The above was just an example of my structure. In fact my data-object contains additional fields, which needs to be included in the `toJsonTree`. Any clue how I can do that?

Comment: This *really* depends. Show an example with two additional fields and I'll see what I can think of. Caveat: My answer is based on Gson documentation. I've never done weird stuff like this before.

Comment: I've updated my question with additional fields inside the data-object.

Comment: @DennisMadsen - I've updated my answer to reflect your change. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to create the `step` variable from the src Step and just remove it's data object? If that's possible I wouldn't have to add the start and end name again.

Comment: @DennisMadsen - There is a way to do that using [`remove`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#remove(java.lang.String)). I highly recommend the rest of the API documentation for JsonObject as well.

Comment: @DennisMadsen - Did you actually implement the serializer and see that it works for you, before marking this answer correct? I'm not too sure because everything I've written is based on Gson documentation. I haven't tested a single line of code I wrote, although the *hope* is that it is fairly correct.

Comment: Yes, I did. It almost worked except from the fact, that I've created a `LocationAdapterFactory` which modify all the locations in my JSON tree, but when I manually add a location, it seems that this isn't changed by my `LocationAdapterFactory`.

Answer (score 3):

In such case I register `TypeAdapter` for nested `data` field. Within the the adapter `data`'s fields are added to parent object. No need to create adapter for enclosing class.

```
public class Step {
    private String startName;
    private endName;
    @JsonAdapter(JsonFlatMapAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, Object> data;
    ...
}

public class JsonFlatMapAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Map<String, Object> value) throws IOException {
        out.nullValue();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        value.forEach((k,v) -> {
            try {
                out.name(k).jsonValue(gson.toJson(v));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. The answer from @ArjunShunkar pointed me in the right direction. I fixed it writing a custom Serializer, but slightly different:

```
public class StepSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Step> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Step src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject step = new JsonObject();
        step.add ("start_name", context.serialize(src.start_name);
        step.add ("end_name",   context.serialize(src.end_name);

        JsonObject data = context.serialize(src.data).getAsJsonObject();
        data.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            step.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        });

        return step;
    }
}
```

This could be improved further, the "start_name" and "end_name" props are still hardcoded. Could be removed by going over the entrySet for the root object and excluding 'data' there, leaving only the element that needs to be unwrapped hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is beautifull way to do it in gson. Maybe get java object (Map) from initial json, remove data, put duration and serialize to json:

```
Map initial = gson.fromJson(initialJson);

// Replace data with duration in this map
Map converted = ...

String convertedJson = gson.toJson(converted);
```